# Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Boolean was expected

Tags: kotlin

i have an error for gesture, this my code error, error in `startActivity(intent)` and `Toast.makeText`

```
R.id.menu_share -> {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://web.whatsapp.com"))
    startActivity(intent)
}
R.id.menu_info -> {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Ada Toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
else -> false
```

Comment: Both `startActivity(intent)` and `Toast.makeText(this,"Ada Toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()` return a `Unit` type while in your `else` statement you are returning `false` which is a `Boolean`. Are you using the `Boolean` value in the else statement? You should probably consider removing it.

Answer (score 1):

We need more code in order to give you a full answer but I can try to assume and give you the closest answer.

`when` can be used in two ways

1. Standalone
2. As an expression

If you use it as a `switch` i.e do different actions based on specific cases
You don't need to return a value and you also don't need an `else` statement

For example:

```
when (menuItem.id) { /** I guess you're trying to perform differet actions based on menu item click */
    R.id.menu_share -> {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://web.whatsapp.com"))
        startActivity(intent)
    } /** returns Unit */

    R.id.menu_info -> {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Ada Toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    } /** returns Unit */

} /** result ignores / Unit */
```

The other way you use a `when` is as an expression and that's when you want the statement to return a value.

In that case, you must fill all possible cases for the type you provided or `else` if the type is something that you can't validate all other options for example `Int`, `String`

For example:

```
val result = when (menuItem.id) { /** I guess you're trying to perform different actions based on menu item click */
    R.id.menu_share -> {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://web.whatsapp.com"))
        startActivity(intent)
    } /** Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Boolean was expected */

    R.id.menu_info -> {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Ada Toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    } /** Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Boolean was expected */

    else -> false /** returns Boolean */

} /** Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Boolean was expected */
```

To fix the issue you need to return the same type on all cases like this

```
val result = when (menuItem.id) { /** I guess you're trying to perform different actions based on menu item click */
    R.id.menu_share -> {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://web.whatsapp.com"))
        startActivity(intent)
        true
    } /** returns Boolean */

    R.id.menu_info -> {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Ada Toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        true
    } /** returns Boolean */

    else -> false /** returns Boolean */

} /** returns Boolean */
```

I hope my explanation answers your question, if not you are more than welcome to comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
R.id.menu_share -> {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://web.whatsapp.com"))
    startActivity(intent)
}
R.id.menu_info -> {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Ada Toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
else -> {
    // you can either left this block empty or just put `return`
}
```